# How to partially differentiate an integral with a density function?

Tags: calculus, integration, self-learning, partial-derivative

I am given this result:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x(t)} \left[\lambda \int u(x(t)) f(t) \mathrm{d}t\right] = \lambda u^\prime(x(t)) f(t)$$
Where $\lambda$ is a constant, and we have the probability density f(t) of the variable $t$ and the functions $x(t)$ and $u(\cdot)$ of $t$ and $x(t)$ respectively.

How do I arrive to this result? Where am I mistaken? Using the chain rule I get:

$$\begin{align*}\frac{\partial}{\partial x(t)} \left[\lambda \int u(x(t)) f(t) \mathrm{d}t \right]&= \lambda \left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial x(t)} \left[\int u(x(t)) f(t) \mathrm{d}t \right]\right] \frac{\partial}{\partial x(t)} u(x(t)) \\
&= \lambda \underbrace{\left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial x(t)} \left[ \int u(x(t)) f(t) \mathrm{d}t \right]\right]}_{\text{this must be } f(t)?} u^\prime(x(t)) 
\end{align*}$$

So we must have: $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x(t)} \left[ \int u(x(t)) f(t) \mathrm{d}t \right] = f(t) $$
But why does this hold?

Comment: Is $\lambda$ a constant? What does $\partial /\partial x(t)$ mean?

Comment: Thanks for the response and apologies for the incomplete question. $\lambda$ is indeed a constant and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x(t)} (\cdot)$ is the partial derivative of the expression in $(\cdot)$ with respect to $x(t)$.